# How to make a WinRE partition with Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB?

Tags: windows, partition, windows-10

We use Win10 Enterprise LTSB with a volume license.

Prior to installation, we spinrite drives, then zero them with dd, to condition them. Then, we just install Windows 10 as normal using the wizard. Once completed, we setup all the standard programs, and finally, take a base image of that machine (using Image for Windows) to use for recovery purposes.

This image is stored on a hidden partition.

The normal installation of Win10 does not appear to install a WinRE partition, but I would like to install one on the hard drive so that I can customize it later with some utilities to restore the base image for these laptops if they are ever out of the office, far-far away, and need to be reset to "after I configured them" defaults.

How do I install WinRE to a partition?